# Reference request on Ehresmann connections

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, connections

I've been asked read up on Ehresmann connections. I have experience in smooth manifold theory, vector bundles, and Riemannian geometry, but I feel in unfamiliar territory after briefly looking into the definition online. Therefore, I would like to find a good book so that I can learn the groundwork required to understand what an Ehresmann connection is.

It seems there are a few ways to characterize an Ehresmann connection. My professor describes it as being defined in terms of a horizontal/vertical splitting for locally trivial fibrations, so I'd like to figure out what this means and how the Ehresmann connection is related to this "splitting".

Comment: I've seen some good chunk of that in [here](https://www.amazon.com/Manifolds-Differential-Geometry-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0821848151).

Comment: I have some short notes on it, see [section 3 here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/principal.pdf).

Comment: @IvoTerek thanks a lot, these look like they start in a place I am familiar with. I will give these a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this and more covered in Tu's book *Differential Geometry: Curvature, Connections, and Characteristic Classes*. Here's the link: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319550824

You'll find this in the later sections of the book, but I would say it's a fairly leisurely read.